# Would my Haskell Game-of-Life be too long to review?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, code-length

I have written a [small application](https://github.com/r-darwish/gameoflife) in Haskell and I wish to get a code review. Since I'm inexperienced, I cannot really write a bullet list of things I'm not satisfied with in my code. It would just be helpful for someone to review the entire application, as any kind advice is welcome.

Is it appropriate to post such a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39170/game-of-life-implementation-in-haskell) on Code Review?

Comment: What size are we talking? From their [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `If you want a code review, you must post the relevant snippets of code in your question. It is fine to post a "see more" link (though, do be careful — very few reviewers will be willing to click through and read thousands of lines of your code), but the most important parts of the code must be placed directly in the question.`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - https://github.com/r-darwish/gameoflife - This is the entire application. It's not a large one.

Comment: @darwish: that's not a problem at all, they're used to a lot more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends. Remember that reviewers are not paid to review your code, so write out your post, then sit back and look at the preview before hitting that <kbd>Post Question</kbd> button. **Put yourself in the reviewers' shoes**. Would you review this?

If you feel it's too much, it probably is. There's nothing wrong with breaking it down into multiple questions.

I haven't looked at your code, but one of the commenters made an interesting comment: "*that's not a problem at all, they're used to a lot more.*" - it's probably true.

Take a look at our [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge) posts, they're all "complete" applications, of reasonable reviewing length.

Comment: I did take a look at the code. A total of approximately 120 lines as far as I could see. Piece of cake!

Comment: +1 for breaking code down into multiple questions.